# Cucumber @Before hook opening multiple browser windows

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

I'm not clear why I am getting 3 chrome browsers opening for the following example.  I have an @Before (cucumber version) annotation to simply setup a chrome webdriver instance before the scenario runs.  As far as I can see, it should open one browser, run scenario (step defs) then close using the @After cucumber hook. What happens is 2 windows open before a third and final window actually executes the steps:

```
Scenario:
    Given I am on the holidays homepage
    When I select the departure location "LON"
    And I select the destination location "PAR"
    And I submit a search
    Then search results are displayed
```

Step Def:

```
public class FindAHolidayStepDefs {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @Given("^I am on the Holidays homepage$")
    public void IAmOnTheThomasCookHomepage() {
        driver.get("http://uat7.co-operativetravel.co.uk/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        String pageTitle = driver.getTitle();

        assertEquals("the wrong page title was displayed !", "Holidays - welcome", pageTitle);
    }


    @When("^I select the departure location \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void ISelectTheDepartureLocation(String departureAirport) {
        WebElement dropDownContainer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class=\"custom-select departurePoint airportSelect\"])[1]"));
        dropDownContainer.click();

        selectOption(departureAirport);
    }

    @When("^I select the destination location \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void ISelectTheDestinationLocation(String destinationAirport) {
        WebElement destinationField = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("(//div[@class=\"searchFormCol destinationAirport\"]/div[@class=\"combinedInput searchFormInput\"]/span/input)[1]")));
        destinationField.sendKeys(destinationAirport);
        selectOption("(" + destinationAirport + ")");
    }


    @When("^I submit a search$")public void iSubmitASearch() throws Throwable {
        WebElement submitButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[@type='submit'])[1]"));
        submitButton.click();
    }


    @Then("^search results are displayed$")
    public void searchResultsAreDisplayed() throws Throwable {
        waitForIsDisplayed(By.xpath(".//*[@id='container']/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/h3"), 30);
        assertThat(checkPageTitle(), equalTo("Package Results"));
    }


    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

When I step through the code in Intellij, the following method is called:

```
private void runHooks(List<HookDefinition> hooks, Reporter reporter, Set<Tag> tags, boolean isBefore)
```

and Intellij reports that hooks paramter = 3 at this point.

```
hooks:  size=3   reporter: "null"  tags:  size = 0  isBefore: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do you have more then one scenario in your feature? -> The @Before method will be executed before each scenario.
- Do you have a different stepdef class with @Before annotated method that opens chrome? -> All @Before methods will be called before a scenario is executed.

Comment: "Do you have more then one scenario in your feature? " - no, only 1 scenario", "Do you have a different stepdef class with @Before annotated method that opens chrome?" - no only one step def!

Comment: Sorry, you were correct, the @Before was also being called twice in 2 other classes

Comment: Then what is the solution for this? The same given should be executed for other scenarios. How to achieve this?

Comment: The docs https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/ say: "Cucumber-JVM does not support running a hook only once", so you need to look for an alternative depending on what you want to achieve.